# What Ethereum applications can I use without having to mine or buy ether?

Tags: dapps

I would like to play around with Ethereum, create contracts, do stuff.

I want to learn, not do anything serious for now. Dao Wars seems like a good start, but it costs 3 ETH just to start trying.

Is there a place where I can start without having to mine or buy ether?

Answer (score 5):

You can use test networks in Ethereum. You can also play around on Eris' platform, which is a private chain that will preallocate things for you and enable you to test out your smart contracts and create games with a permissioned layer.

https://docs.erisindustries.com/tutorials/getting-started/

Answer (score 4):

Download Mist wallet here: [Mist Wallet](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.6.2) (*Windows, Mac or Linux*), connect to the Testnet (`Top Menu: Develop/Network/Testnet`), wait for wallet to sincronize blocks, once finished you can start mining to get some ETHER (`Top Menu: Develop/Start Mining`) on the Testnet, it will take you no more that 5 minutes to get some ETHER on your Wallet.

**Note:** ETHER you mine on Testnet is only valid there.

Once you have some ETHER you can deploy some sample contracts like the one described here: [Create your own token](https://www.ethereum.org/token).

Hope this helps.